# Access smarty loop property in included file?

Tags: php, properties, foreach, include, smarty

When using smarty it provides a few useful `@properties` on the looping key such as `@first` `@last` and `@iteration`.

But it seems that in loops that look like

```
{foreach $collection as $item}
    {include file="something_else.tpl"}
{/foreach}
```

We seem to lose the `@properties`.

If I want access to those properties is there a more elegant way than passing all the properties to the included file?

```
{foreach $collection as $item}
    {include file="something_else.tpl" first=$item@first last=$item@last iter...}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use the `@properties` inside the loop, they will be calculated and available also in the included files:

```
{foreach $collection as $item}
    {if $item@first || $item@last || $item@iteration}{/if} {* Force @properties to be calculated so they can be used in included files *}
    {include file="something_else.tpl"}
{/foreach}
```

It seems that the `@properties` don't event have to be used in the template logic, but it's enough if they are inside a comment. Then you can avoid having empty `if` conditions in your compiled template files. The following currently works, though I'm not sure if it's intended.

```
{foreach $collection as $item}
    {* $item@first $item@last $item@iteration Force @properties to be calculated so they can be used in included files *}
    {include file="something_else.tpl"}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically no.
But maybe you can use a mixed syntax. You add a name to the foreach and try to access its properties via {$smarty.foreach.name.property}.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl
(search for $smarty.foreach.)